# Call deployed smart contract from web3.js

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have small test smart contract, which is deployed to my test network. And I want to use a server to call the function in the contract. Here is the code:
payontime.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract payontime{
  address public remitter;
  address private remittee;
  uint value;
  bool public start;

  /*Only owner can use these function*/
  modifier onlyOwner(){
    if(msg.sender != remitter) throw;
    _;
  }

  /*Initialize the owner*/
  function payontime(address receiver) payable{
    remitter = msg.sender;
    value = msg.value;
    remittee = receiver;
    start = true;
    if(!remittee.send(value)){
        throw;
    }
  }

  function wakeUp() public returns (string){
    return "success" ; 
  }

  function getContractAddr() public returns(address){
    return this;
  }

  /*Get the remittee*/
  function getRemitee() public returns(address){
    return remittee;
  }
}
```

I use `truffle serve` and a webpage to new the contract.

app.js

```
import { default as Web3} from 'web3';
import { default as contract } from 'truffle-contract'
import payontime_artifacts from '../../build/contracts/payontime.json'
var payontime = contract(payontime_artifacts);

window.App = {
    sendCoin : function(){

        var sender = web3.eth.accounts[0];
        var receiver = document.getElementById('receiver').value;
        var amount =         parseInt(document.getElementById('amount').value);
    web3.eth.getBalance(receiver,function(error,result){
        if(!error){
            consol.log("Before transfer: " + result );
        }else{
            console.log("Error: " + error);
        }
    });

    var newContract = payontime.new(receiver,{from:sender, value:amount}).then(
        function(myPay){
            console.log(myPay.getContractAddr.call());
        }).then(
        function(){
            web3.eth.getBalance(receiver,function(error,result){
                if(!error){
                    console.log("After transfer: " + result );
                }else{
                    console.log("Error: " + error);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    console.warn("Using web3 detected from external source. If you find that your accounts don't appear or you have 0 MetaCoin, ensure you've configured that source properly. If using MetaMask, see the following link. Feel free to delete this warning. :) http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/truffle-and-metamask")
    // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
    window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
    console.warn("No web3 detected. Falling back to http://localhost:8545. You should remove this fallback when you deploy live, as it's inherently insecure. Consider switching to Metamask for development. More info here: http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/truffle-and-metamask");
    // fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
    window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
  }
  payontime.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
});
```

`app.js` logs the address `0x1d379f2ab48ad20319e9f81cb45af415aa6f2966` , and I want to use this address to call the `wakeUp()` in the `payontime.sol` through another application `index.js`.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');

/* Connect to ethereum node */
const etherUrl = "http://localhost:8545";
const abi = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"wakeUp","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"getContractAddr","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"remitter","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"start","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"getRemitee","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"receiver","type":"address"}],"payable":true,"type":"constructor"}];

let web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider(etherUrl));


/*Call the function which already deployed on ethereum network
  Notice: ABI have to modifeid when the smart contract code change*/
var contractInstance = web3.eth.contract(abi).at('0x1d379f2ab48ad20319e9f81cb45af415aa6f2966');
var reply = "false";
reply = contractInstance.wakeUp.call(function(error,result){
    if(error){
        console.log("Error");
        throw error;
    }else{
        return result;
    }
});
console.log(reply);
```

But there is an error message:
`BigNumber Error: new BigNumber() not a base 16 number` 
 I found it might be caused by not [fully synced](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1741/what-does-the-web3-bignumber-not-a-base-16-number-error-mean). I think it have some problem when I call the function in a deployed contract. So how can I call a deployed contract from web.js?

Comment: try `BigNumber.value` in your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The BigNumber() is not a base 16 number error can happen in many cases, yet the causes are not necessarily the same. I believe the original post's issue is with using Events that index on "string" types, which I'm running into as well. If my contract event marks a "string" type as "indexed", i get the same error. But if I restrict the "indexed" keyword to only "address" type, I'm fine. I'm trying to find documentation on what data types can be "indexed" in a contract event, but to no avail. My gut feeling is anything that can be parsed as a number (address, integers etc) might be OK. I don't think blockchain synching is the issue here.
So try removing any indexes on string fields in the event definition for now until they fix the bug.

ref:- [What does the Web3 "BigNumber not a base 16 number Error" mean](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1741/what-does-the-web3-bignumber-not-a-base-16-number-error-mean)

Answer (score 0):

From documentation of [web3.js 1.0](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id12)  we can call method from web3js as :

> myContract.methods.myMethod([param1[, param2[, ...]]])

Lets see the example

```
var Web3 = require('web3')
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
const abi = abi_of_contract
const Contract = web3.eth.contract(abi)
var contractaddress = address_of_deployed_contract
const contractInstance = Contract.at(contractaddress)

//here I am using default account as first account from the list of addresses in the rpc enabled node
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0]

//calling contract function wakeUp()  

 contractInstance.wakeUp(   
        {
            from:   web3.eth.defaultAccount,
            to:     contractaddress           
    });
```

Error   `Error: new BigNumber() not a base 16 number`
 that you got may be due to address you have passed. 
Please make account that you are using as default account first. It may solve your problem.